# Karbonn Titanium S1 suddenly switches off

Tags: battery, karbonn

My Karbonn Titanium S1 smartphone switches off when I open the gallery, play any game, listen to music or do anything with the phone without connecting the charger. The screen starts to shrink and the phone is switched off. After restarting the phone battery is empty.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Well,that's weird maybe you should try performing factory reset to see if that helps you out ! And if it still doesn't then better would be talking it to the customer support as it may be happening because of some hardware problems.

Comment: Is the battery indicator on the phone showing full charge before you disconnect it?

Answer (score 0):

> and after restarting the phone battery is empty.

This shows the battery of the phone is dead. You will need to replace the battery to stop the sudden drain like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same phone . I changed my battery and everything is OK   now